# How do I input signed number to array in TypeScript?

Tags: typescript

I want find largest number in given array and negative numbers are also included in that

TypeScript is used to solve this problem

but problem here is  '-' sign is also taken as character input in each index
so, how to get number as input along with its sign in array

```
var readline=requre("readline-sync")
var arr:number[]=readline.question("Enter numbers ")
    var max:number=0
    for(var i=-0;i<arr.length;i++){
        if(arr[i]>max){
            max=arr[i]
        }
    }
    console.log(max);
```

input is -5 -6 -7 -1
expected output  -1
actual output 7

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you are getting a `string` back from `readline.question()` (as implied [here](https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/blob/master/types/readline-sync/index.d.ts#L39)) but are treating it as `number[]`.  I'm not sure why this doesn't give you an error in your TypeScript compiler.  I'd strongly recommend compiling with the `--strict` [compiler option](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/compiler-options.html) and paying attention to your dependency libraries, etc.

So I'll replace `readline` with my own version that does what I think you're seeing when you enter `-5 -6 -7 -1` at runtime:

```
// what I assume your readlineSync dependency is doing:
namespace readline {
  export function question(prompt: string): string {
    return "-5 -6 -7 -1";
  }
}
```

Now you should see that the following is an error:

```
var arr: number[] = readline.question("Enter numbers "); // error!
// Type 'string' is not assignable to type 'number[]'.
```

The way to fix this is to split the string into non-whitespace chunks and parse each piece into a number.  I am *assuming* that you will always separate by whitespace and not commas or other delimiters:

```
arr = (readline.question("Enter numbers").match(/\S+/g) || []).map(n => +n);
console.log(arr);
```

(Note, if the line entered is all whitespace, `.match(\S+/g)` will return `null`.  I assume that should be treated as an empty list, which is why I did `|| []`.  If you want that to be an error condition, you can just do it in steps, checking if the result of `match()` is `null` and throwing an error or something).

Now `arr` is a genuine array of numbers, and your code will return `-1` as you expec... oh, wait:

```
var max: number = 0; 
for (var i = -0; i < arr.length; i++) {
  if (arr[i] > max) {
    max = arr[i];
  }
}
console.log(max); // 0, not -1
```

Zero?  Ohh, you initialized `max` to `0`.  That's not going to work.  Let's fix that in one of the many possible ways to interpret what it means to take a maximum of a list of numbers.  I'm going to assume that the "empty maximum" (i.e., the maximum of a list of no numbers) is `-Infinity`.  This might seem a bit crazy, but it works for the same reason the [empty sum](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Empty_sum) is `0` and the [empty product](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Empty_product) is `1`: they are all [identity elements](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Identity_element) for their respective operations.  Adding `0` to a sum doesn't change it; multiplying a product by `1` doesn't change it; adding `-Infinity` to a list you're taking the maximum of doesn't change the maximum.

```
max = -Infinity; // anything will be bigger than this  
for (var i = -0; i < arr.length; i++) {
  if (arr[i] > max) {
    max = arr[i];
  }
}
console.log(max); // -1 as desired
```

Great!  Of course, once we're going down the road of cleaning up the actual max-finding code, we'd be remiss in not remarking that the kids nowadays love functional programming:

```
max = arr.reduce((acc, n) => (n > acc ? n : acc), -Infinity); 
console.log(max); // also -1
```

Or that finding the maximum of a list of numbers is something JavaScript [already does](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/max) and you don't need to reinvent the wheel:

```
max = Math.max(...arr);
console.log(max); // also -1
```

(Aside: note that `Math.max(...[])` also returns `-Infinity`.)

[Link to code](http://www.typescriptlang.org/play//#code/PTAEHcAsEMBdQJKmgZxQVwLYFNQE8B7dAJ1GO2gBMAbASwDtsBlPegY1EuwAdt6v2eULRScCDAOYAuALAAoetBwpu0NrnJU6jUAG95oUNgAe3AsXgAzdO1i0C9UAEd02FHYcAKbsQKZusFKg7sSSAJRBIZJ6BoZk2LAkjgBEALQArKCpAGxZAOxZAIzJANyxAL7ylXLyAG7QpA3EQfRYAEbYxADaALqgALzxWgzYAHQubh70nskAovSwnaCtmB3EoslhJaAgRsS+xACE8rsAKni8oADkUfQSV8Ki9ATwqCi0Eopt1LiwBKCwC64K4rNa9K6jeQnMAmWDENTwZ70VJQWiLFRqXBsSA2ADWomg-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)

Answer (score 0):

If you are taking user input, you'll need to change the input from strings to actual numbers.

This example makes everything an integer, but you can use `parseFloat` if required.

```
const arr: number[] = ['1', '3', '5', '-8'].map((val) => parseInt(val, 10));
const max: number = Math.max.apply(null, arr);
console.log(max); // 5
```

This example returns `5`.

Using your original example, we get `-1` as expected:

```
const arr: number[] = ['-5', '-6', '-7', '-1'].map((val) => parseInt(val, 10));
const max: number = Math.max.apply(null, arr);
console.log(max); // -1
```

Here's the plain JavaScript version, so you can run it straight from this answer:

```js
const arr = ['-5', '-6', '-7', '-1'].map((val) => parseInt(val, 10));
const max = Math.max.apply(null, arr);
console.log(max);
```